# C program crashes after char input

Tags: c

I am new to the C programming language and I've been trying to make a little text-based game in it. The input is very simple, as the user needs to input `S` or `s` and `N` or `n`.

The problem is, when I run the program and feed input to `choice`, the program simply stops working.

Here's the code:

```
/*O jogo */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "story.h"

int main() {
  char choice;
  puts(intro);
  scanf("%c", &choice);
  if (choice == 's' || choice == 'S') {
    puts(dialog0);
    puts(dialog1);
    puts(dialog2);
    puts(dialog3);
    puts(dialog4);
    puts(dialog5);
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    if (choice == 's' || choice == 'S')
      puts(dialog6option1);
    else if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') {
      puts(dialog6option2);
      puts(dialog6option2pt2);
    }

    puts(dialog6);
    puts(dialog7);
    puts(dialog8);
    puts(dialog9);
    puts(dialog10);
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    if (choice == 's' || choice == 'S') {
      puts(dialog10option1);
      puts(dialog10option1pt2);
    } else if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') {
      puts(dialog10option2);
      puts(dialog10option2pt2);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Second scanf requires a space before carrying on...

Comment: Please don't tag questions as both [tag:c] and [tag:c++]. Chose the right one beforehand, unless it's about the cross-section between both languages.

Comment: what are the `dialog<n>`s?

Comment: *The program simply stops working* is not very descriptive. Care to clarify?

Comment: Do you reach the second scanf ? Does it print the value of `dialog0`

Comment: What happens when you don't enter either `s` or `n` (or uppercase)?

Comment: _"feed input to `choice`,"_ maybe important here... show us please.

Comment: Oh, sorry! It's my first time here.

Comment: Actually, I've imported all the "dialogs" from another archive.
As for the input, I put n,N,s and S, but none of these chars seem to work. 
I've even tried to put "a" in the program, but it doesn't work.
I don't really know if the problem is at the _scanf_ or the _if_ functions, all I know is that the program ends there.
No, it doesn't print dialog0.
The following message is shown when the program stops working:
"Game.exe stopped working"

Comment: I actually thought it was a pretty simple mistake that I didn't see, that's why I didn't give you a better description.

Answer (score 1):

The program I compiled does not "stop working" (I filled in the missing strings). It simply exits when I enter `'n'` at the first response, because, to summarise, it is like this.

```
int main() {
    char choice;
    puts(intro);
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if (choice == 's' || choice == 'S') {
        //  ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So `'n'` simply exits the program, otherwise when I start with `'s'` and then continue with `'n'` or `'s'` I get the printed dialogs. Although as I commented above, what is supposed to happen when neither `'n'` or `'s'` are entered?

BTW you have no prompts to help the user know what they are supposed to enter, or why.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space within your first `scanf`:

```
...
puts(intro);
scanf(" %c", &choice);  /* missing the space in your code*/
...
```

Comment: Please explain why that is needed and will solve the problem?

Comment: That won't probably do much unless he is deliberately inserting whitespace characters before entering the first input character, which is unlikely, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `scanf` is interesting especially when you include whitespace in the format string.  When I wrote more console-oriented applications and wasn't using something like curses, I used a function like the following to read input:

```
char
get_next_input(void)
{
        int ch;
        while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF) {
                if (!isspace(ch)) {
                        return (char)ch;
                }
        }
        return (char)'\0';
}
```

It returns the next non-whitespace character in the stream or `'\0'` on EOF.  I found it more reliable than using `scanf` across various implementations.

The problem that you are probably experiencing is line buffering on `stdin`.  The call to `scanf` might not return until you press enter (e.g., enter a newline character).

Comment: This `get_next_input()` function sounds like an overly complicated method for ignoring whitespaces. Why not insert a whitespace in scanf's format string? I don't see how this might be a better approach.